# How do I select and print data from text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Text data inside text would be like:

```
Name=KenKen
ID=123456
Phone Number=88888888
```

And the preferred output would be:

```
print(n)
print(i)
print(p)
```

```
KenKen
123456
88888888
```

If anyone knows how, please teach me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is the code that you tried?

Comment: May I recommend looking into taking a Python tutorial?  It’ll give you a great foundation for learning. Including the basics such as this.

Comment: Straight from the official Python Tutorial: [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) (you'll want to read the *reading* part here).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
with open('file/path', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines(): # f.readlines() read the file as list of lines
        print(line.split("=")[-1]) # splits each line by = into list, and takes the last element
```

Answer (score -1):

it seems that you want to extract the data from the file after the equal sign then follow the steps:

```
desired_data = [] # we will store the extracted data KenKen 123456 88888888 in this case
file_data = "Name=KenKen\nID=123456\nPhone Number=88888888" # file_data where "\n" are the new lines

# print(file_data) you can try this command here if you want to check that your data is taken in the right form or not

file_data = file_data.split("\n") # seperated the data in the desired format

# print(file_data) gives ['Name=KenKen', 'ID=123456', 'Phone Number=88888888']

for line in file_data:
    index = line.index("=") + 1 # as the data is after equal sign, we will find index it then slice the string
    data = line[index:] # sliced the string or line[index:] is the substring starting from the index value to the last
    data = data.strip() # rids off any unwanted spaces around the text
    desired_data.append(data) # we will store the data in the above declared list and then print them all

for i in desired_data: # iterating through the list and printing the items
    print(i)
```